# Тетрис libgdx падения фигур

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Как сделать так чтобы фигуры тетриса опускались вниз с использованием libgdx Eclipse? Фигурки сами рендерятся. Но двигаться вниз не желают. Как правильно написать нужный метод?

```
Square[] shape = world.shape.getArray();
text = FactoryShape.setColor(shape[0].color);

for (int i = 0; i <  shape.length; i++) {
    batch.draw(text, shape[i].position.x, shape[i].position.y)
}
```

Вот если например указать shape[i].position.y-- то фигурка пойдет вниз, но она не зафиксируется после падения.

Comment: Вам нужно получить координаты нижней линии того пространства в котором вы прорисовываете   shape[i] и сравнивать y, когда координаты совпадут остановить падение этой фигуры. Еще скорее всего понадобится учесть высоту фигуры.

Comment: А что насчёт следующего варианта? Например когда фигура падает  на фигуру? Как там её остановить. Создать столкновения?

Comment: Если рассуждать логически, то фигуры состоят из кубиков. Чтобы не производить лишних расчетов - может считать сначала габариты фигуры и потом - какой стороной она повернута? Сделать состояние фигуры - зафиксирована. Повернута на столько -то, всего 4 состояния фигуры. Она может быть повернута только одной стороной к полу. Тогда вам нужно будет учитывать и линию пола и фигуры лежащие на полу.